# javascript get the details base on of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I Have 2 sets data the setA which consist of arrays and setB which consist of array of object

```
setA = ["1", "5", "3"];
setB =[
        {"_id": "1", "name": "jobert", "age": "30"},
        {"_id": "2", "name": "alex", "age": "30"},
        {"_id": "3", "name": "dianne", "age": "30"},
        {"_id": "4", "name": "jhon", "age": "30"},
        {"_id": "5", "name": "matt", "age": "30"},
      ];
```

i want to show the result as: jobert, matt, dianne

how can i do this on react native?

Comment: Same way as in JS vanilla. Loop `setB` and gather objects with proper ID

Comment: thank you, very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter elements from setB on the basis of setA first and then use `map` to return only name property from objects in filtered array.

```js
let setA = ["1", "5", "3"];
let setB =[
        {"_id": "1", "name": "jobert", "age": "30"},
        {"_id": "2", "name": "alex", "age": "30"},
        {"_id": "3", "name": "dianne", "age": "30"},
        {"_id": "4", "name": "jhon", "age": "30"},
        {"_id": "5", "name": "matt", "age": "30"},
      ];
      
let filteredData = setB.filter(elem => setA.includes(elem._id));
let result = filteredData.map((elem) => elem.name);

console.log(result);
```